# What is the significance of “Homomorphism”?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, learning, group-homomorphism, motivation

Certainly **Homomorphism** is a prerequisite  to establish an “**Isomorphism**”(Bijection),  but  what does a **Homomorphism** tell *independently* when it is established between  two sets?

**Homomorphism** relates two sets as it is defined. But does it tell anything else? Or it is a tool for relating two sets only.

It would be nice to have  an example where **Homomorophism** plays  a big role besides being a  condition for **Isomorphism**?

Comment: Homomorphisms are as essential to group theory and ring theory as continuous functions are to topology.

Comment: A homomorphism preserves operation, in order words preserves the structure from one set to another. It plays a similar or analogous role of continuous functions in Topology and rigid movements in Geometry.

Comment: "Homo = the same" and "morph = form" When $f: A\to B$, the word homomorphism apply if $A$ having a structure $f(A)$ conserve this structure as subset of $B$

Comment: @AaronMaroja , "A homomorphism preserves operation" sounds good, is it like"if I can do addition in A, I can perform same thing in B" and this implies Both A, B has a "common property" (roughly speaking)?

Comment: @Jim An example you could work to visualize this is the homomorphism of $(\mathbb R, +)$ the addition group of real numbers and $(S^1, \cdot)$ the unitary circle with product, through the map $ x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$. Ir preverves operation meaning, $\phi (a + b) = \phi (a) \cdot \phi (b)$.

Comment: I'm okay with "homomorphism preserves operation". However, I'm not okay with "homomorphism preserves structure". Saying a trivial function preserves structure is not a good thing, imo.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo ,  structure preserving is for Isomorphism, right?

Comment: It does preserve "some" of the structure though, see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158323/in-what-sense-of-structure-do-group-homomorphisms-preserve-structure) and also this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242348/intuition-on-group-homomorphisms).

Comment: Are you studying group theory?  Wait a few weeks, you will some to the (first, second, and third) homomorphism theorems.

Comment: @AaronMaroja That is a philosophical aspect, a point of view, not a mathematical fact. To me, saying that a homomorphism preserves structure is the same thing as saying that if I took all the copper beams from a skyscraper and made 3 schools, I would have "preserved the structure" of the skyscraper. Saying preserve "*some* structure" is okay, though, and completely different from "preserving the structure". Again, this is a *philosophical* aspect. Nonetheless, the measure of "exactly how much" structure is preserved by a homomorphism is given by the *isomorphism* theorem.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo  yes, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

You are given two sets $A$ and $B$, both provided with a binary operation $*\>$. This means that in $A$ as well as in $B$ for certain triples $x$, $y$, $z$ it is true that $z=x*y\>$; e.g., $13=5+8$, or $91=7\cdot 13$. A map $\phi:\>A\to B$ is a *homomorphism* if it preserves such "incidences":
$$z=x*y\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \phi(z)=\phi(x)*\phi(y)\ .$$