# Polynomial has no integers root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Polynomial P has degree n. Prove if for some $k\in \mathbb{N},  \ P(k),P(k+1)$ is odd, then $P$ has no integers root. Could you give me some clue?

Comment: **Hint** The hypotheses imply it has not roots mod $2$ hence no integer roots - see the [Parity Root Test.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158345/242)  (assuming the polynomial has *integer* coefficients)

Comment: The problem incorrect; there are certainly polynomials with $P(0) = P(1) = 1$ and $P(2) = 0$. Perhaps you mean that $P(k)$ is odd for *all* $k \in\mathbb{N}$ - but in that case there is no reason to also say that $P(k+1)$ is odd. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited after Arthur comment.

If $P$ has integer coefficients, let $a$ be a integer root. Then $P=(x-a)Q$ and $Q$ has integer coefficients. Now compute the parity of P(k), P(k+1).

For the remaining case, note that $P(x)=x(x+1)/2$ verifies P(1)=1, P(2)=3 are odd and $P$ has integer roots.

Comment: Just a small thing to point out: are you certain that $Q$ has integer coefficients (or at the very least takes integer values at $k$ and $k+1$)? Or am I just too tired to see that it is obvious?

Comment: and also, what about $Q(k)$ and $Q(k+1)$ ?

Comment: Thank you, Arthur. I have edited.

Comment: Excellent answer! now with the distinction  P with *integer / non-integer* coefficients, your previous idea became clear, making also clear that the claim in the post **only applies to P with integer coefficients**.